# SwiftUI: How to prevent bottom sheet move up to full screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The `ContentView` popups the bottom sheet when press "+":

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button("+") {
                isShowingAddingItem.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingAddingItem) {
                AddingItemView(done: { item in
                    theItems.append(item)
                }).presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            }
        }

}
```

This is the bottom sheet view:

```
struct AddingItemView: View {

    @State var price: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("test")
                TextField("Please input price", text: $price)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }.padding()


            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.white)


    }

}
```

[image]

When the keyboard appears, then all the content is moved up to the top of the screen. That is the sheet isn't on the bottom which achieved by `.presentationDetents([.medium, .large])` .

[image]

Anyway to disable the keyboard pushing the content up?

Comment: What happens if you just use `.presentationDetents([.medium])`?

Comment: Just a bit lower. Still not the bottom sheet. Also tried `[.medium, .medium]`.

Comment: And what happens if you force the `height` with `.presentationDetents([.height(400)])`? Here's a useful link: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-display-a-bottom-sheet

Comment: Still doesn't work, I think the issue is `.presentationDetents` was disabled.

Comment: That is probably a convenience thing with iOS. I cannot remember any app I used so far, in which the keyboard didn't push the bottomSheet all the way to the top.

Comment: I agree, Apple engineers had to make sure the keyboard was always displayed at 100%.

Comment: what if you set `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` for the view?

Comment: @timbretimbre doesn't work.

Comment: When the keyboard is on screen, a sheet will always go to full size. The only way around it is to make a custom sheet.